# missing ',' before statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var value= "200,000.00 $";
var ft_PriceTotal = eval(value.replace(" $", ""));
```

I can't figure out why this error is being raised `missing , after statement`
can someone tell me how can i fix this error ?

Comment: Type `200,000.00` in your console :-) (that's the code getting `eval`-ed).

Comment: please note that `eval` should be used with caution. Here, you can use `parseFloat` instead (see T.J. Crowder's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `eval` runs **code**, and you're asking it to run the code `"200,000.00"`.

If your goal is to parse that string into a number, use `parseFloat`, but you'll want to remove the commas, too:

```
var value= "200,000.00 $";
var ft_PriceTotal = parseFloat(value.replace(/[ $,]/g, ""));
```

Or `+` works too:

```
var value= "200,000.00 $";
var ft_PriceTotal = +value.replace(/[ $,]/g, "");
```

The difference is that `parseFloat` will stop as of the first non-number character it finds, but `+` requires the *entire* string to be the number. So `parseFloat("123.4xyz")` is `123.4`, but `+"123.4xyz"` is `NaN`.

Note that this assumes `,` is the thousands separator, as it is in your example. Many countries use `,` as a decimal separator, so the above wouldn't be appropriate for them. But your example uses `,` for thousands, so...